# How to add security annotation to template?

Tags: templates, grails, groovy

I would like my templates to be smarter about generating controllers.  In my domain classes I have specified an enum with the properties that should be added to the security annotation in the controller.

```
static enum SecurityProperties {
    ROLE_SUPER_USER( "ROLE_SUPER_USER" ),
    IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY( "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" )

    SecurityProperties( String s ) {
        this.s = s
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }        
}
```

I would like the template to look at this enum and create the security annotation in a controller when the controller is generated.  I use the templates a lot and it is a major annoyance to run `generate-all` then have to add the security annotations back in for all of my controllers.

My problem is that I am having issues accessing the enum from the template because I cannot get the domain class.

I usually get a domain class like this:

```
grailsApplication.getArtefact( "Domain", "myDomainClass" )?.getClazz()
```

But `grailsApplication` is not available in the template.

What other Grails / Groovy way is there to get the class or make `grailsApplication` available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the scaffolding templates you have a `domainClass` variable available to you which contains the `GrailsDomainClass`, so `domainClass.clazz` should give you what you need.

Comment: Awesome. I think I actually tried this once but it failed.  Now I see it failed because it didn't like the enum for some reason.  I put the values in a list instead and I can access it fine.  Thanks!